# vb.net How to detect specific string on HTML code

Tags: vb.net, basic

**Hello everyone** i am building a program to find specific strings on a HTML source code. Here is what i mean ->

For example the first thing the program does is "Grab target's HTML code and put it on RichTextBox1.text"

When i grab HTML code and put it on RichTextBox1.text i search for keyword " {"list" "

Somewhere in HTML code we can see " {"list" " right here ->

[IMAGE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrtv2t03c5cs3yy/snapshot1.png) (open in new tab :D)

As you can see there are some numbers there. I like to store those strings in different variables.

So my Main questions is: "How can i grab these little things from a huge HTML code?"

Comment: Learn to use an HTML Parser. This one is considered one of the best [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As Steve said in the comment, you should try to learn how to program with a Html Parser library - I presonally love Html Agility Pack, but there are many more(mshtml library etc).

The main idea behind these methods is that you can download the Html text (by using DOM or any other method) and than "find your way" through the tag hierarchy of the html code, usually by using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/), which will generate you results (finding the text you want).